# Two or more calcul in a request in PLSQL

Tags: plsql, count, sum

I'm trying to make two agregations and return the values in a stored procedure.
This is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE T_TEST (TEST NUMERIC(10) ) ;
INSERT INTO T_TEST VALUES (1) ;
INSERT INTO T_TEST VALUES (2) ;
INSERT INTO T_TEST VALUES (3) ;
```

This works :

```
DECLARE
  vSUM NUMERIC(10) ;
  vCOUNT NUMERIC(10) ;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(TEST) AS SUM INTO vSUM FROM T_TEST ;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vSUM) ;
END;
```

outside of the sp, this works ;

```
SELECT SUM(TEST) AS SUM , COUNT(TEST) AS NB FROM T_TEST ;
```

but this doesn't :

```
 DECLARE
   vSUM NUMERIC(10) ;
   vCOUNT NUMERIC(10) ;
 BEGIN
   SELECT 
     SUM(TEST) AS SUM INTO vSUM, 
     COUNT(TEST) AS NB INTO vCOUNT
   FROM T_TEST ;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vSUM) ;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vCOUNT) ;
 END;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your syntax is slightly off.  Try the following:

```
 DECLARE
     vSUM NUMERIC(10);
     vCOUNT NUMERIC(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(TEST), COUNT(TEST)   -- SELECT and INTO lists should appear
    INTO vSUM, vCOUNT               -- grouped together separately
    FROM T_TEST;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vSUM);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vCOUNT);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid variable declaration like bellow:

```
BEGIN
  for x in (
    SELECT 
        SUM(TEST)   sum_o_test
      , COUNT(1)    count_o_test
    FROM T_TEST
  ) loop 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sum_o_test:'  ||x.sum_o_test);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('count_o_test:'||x.count_o_test);
  end loop;
END;
```